# png files needed to be converted to pickle files

Tags: python-3.x, png, pickle

I am new to pickle and struggling with converting to pickle files from png. My png files are in a local directory.

I know the conversion can be done with the below code:-

```
file = open('data.pkl', 'wb')

# Pickle dictionary using protocol 0.
pickle.dump(image, file)
file.close()
```

I was trying below:-

```
import pickle
with open("png1.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump('png1.png', file)
```

This is taking time and I am spinning around what can be done?